# Unable to run other projects from a wrapper project in a solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core project(WebAPI) - "Project 1".

I have a console application(WebSocket) - "Project 2".

I have a driver project, "Project 3" which have references to Project 1 and Project 2.

Problem: How to start Project 1 and Project 2 from Project 3. If I make i try to call main after adding reference,  the project 2/project 1 is unable to find the app.config file.

P.S. : I think the path is creating an issue, because I am starting one project from other and root path is different.

Tried using:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa3e311e-0bfe-4838-9688-72b3c1dde13f/how-to-call-another-project-from-a-project-in-the-same-solution?forum=Vsexpressvcs

```
private void callProject2()
{
    Project2 pb = new Project2()
    Process.Start(pb.returnPath() + "Project2.exe");
}
```

but, unable to find .exe file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by following these 2 steps,

1. compiling Project 1 and Project 2 as a class library rather than console application.
2. copying configuration settings of Project 1 and Project 2 to Project 3.

CODE: //called startup method of project 2 and 1 from main of project 3.

PROJECT 3:

```
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
               Project2.Stratup();
               Project1.Stratup();
            }
```

Done!