# Start 2 servers on 2 different threads from a console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to start 2 ASP.NET core WEB API project from a console application?

I want to start 2 server from a console application, on two different threads.

I have 2 Asp.net core Web API projects, and I want to call Main method of both these projects on different threads from a console application.

Like:

```
Console application -
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WebAPI1());
          Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WebAPI2());
          Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
          Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
    }


        public void WebAPI1()
        {
           //make a call to web api 1 main method
        }
        public void WebAPI2()
        {
           //make a call to web api 2 main method
        }
```

I am trying this amnd failing on various fronts, does it make sense doing sense. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: This is the problem : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167634/unable-to-run-other-projects-from-a-wrapper-project-in-a-solution